# I want to change the background color of checkbox button at the time of focus in android

Tags: android, xml, checkbox

I want to change the color of check box button as when it gets focus its background color will change and when it has no focus it will remain the same.

I have tried using selector but not able to change it
can any one help me out in this

Comment: Can you share what you done already

Comment: `    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_tnc_signin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/white_70"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_bg_selector"
                                            android:nextFocusUp="@id/checkbox_remember_me_signin" /> '

Comment: `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_selected_state" />
   
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unselected_state"/>


</selector>  `

Comment: ` <vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="16"     android:viewportWidth="17" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillAlpha="0.5" android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M4.3813,0.6687L12.7413,0.6687A3,3 0,0 1,15.7413 3.6687L15.7413,12.0211A3,3 0,0 1,12.7413 15.0211L4.3813,15.0211A3,3 0,0 1,1.3813 12.0211L1.3813,3.6687A3,3 0,0 1,4.3813 0.6687z"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.5" android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
` unseleted_state

Comment: these are the xml i have created

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Backround-color: 'any color'
```

Comment: but it will change whole checkbox color but i want to change only the button color not the text color

Comment: It actually Won't

Answer (score 0):

Create drawable file like this :

checkbox_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/pink"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/checkbox_not_selected"/>
</selector>
```

Apply it like this :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_23sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_23sdp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:buttonTint="@drawable/checkbox_color"
                android:checked="false"
                android:clickable="false" />
```

then change it runtime like this to change color runtime based on of it is selected :

```
chkSelected.isSelected = true
```

or

```
chkSelected.isSelected = false
```

Answer (score 0):

add a new color file in your project. (right click on res then new>android recourse file and put the recourse type  on Color )
fill this file with this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#ce0e0e" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="#6fc97d"/>
</selector>
```

then in your `CheckBox` add this color as your checkBox Color.

you can change your color when checked is true or false in your sample color file